# error when trying to get data from "data"

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting this error when trying to get data from my "data".

```
child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream:
                  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messages').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                  case ConnectionState.none:
                  case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                    return Center(
                      // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  default:
                    List<DocumentSnapshot> documents =
                        snapshot.data!.docs.reversed.toList();
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: documents.length,
                        reverse: true,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ChatMessage(documents[index].data); erro here
                        });
                }
              },
            ),
```

estou usando ChatMessage(this.data);
final Map<String, dynamic> data;

[image]
[image]

Comment: From a **DocumentSnapshot** you say **.data()** not just **data** so try changing it like **ChatMessage(documents[index].data())**.

Comment: the error still persists this way that passed "(documents[index].data())"

Comment: erro: Contains all the data of this document snapshot.

The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that what you wrote is not exactly the same as what is in the photo, for text it is just `.date` and for the photo it is `.data()`

Assuming that it is `.data` always the parentheses, it is possible to use the cast if you are sure that the type that is in date is the same type that will go into `ChatMessage`  if it is you can do that

```
return ChatMessage(documents[index].data.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>());
```

Answer (score 0):

The class definition of `DocumentSnapshot` looks like `DocumentSnapshot<T extends Object?>`, with `T` being the generic parameter. The error in your code says:

> The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'Map<String, dynamic>'

This hints to the fact that your `ChatMessage` class constructor expects an input of type `Map<String, dynamic>` but `data()` of `DocumentSnapshot` returns `T?` (https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html). Since you did not provide `DocumentSnapshot` with a concrete type it assumes it to be `Object?`.

One solution here is to provide `DocumentSnapshot` with the concrete type you expect it to store/return. In your case that would be here:

```
List<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> documents =
                        snapshot.data!.docs.reversed.toList();
```

Furthermore you need to cast away the nullability of `T?`, otherwise you would get another error (notice the postfix exclamation mark):

```
return ChatMessage(documents[index].data()!);
```